# class which cannot be derived

Tags: c++

I found this code [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty)

```
class Usable;

class Usable_lock {
    friend class Usable;
private:
    Usable_lock() {}
    Usable_lock(const Usable_lock&) {}
};

class Usable : public virtual Usable_lock {
    // ...
public:
    Usable();
    Usable(char*);
    // ...
};

Usable a;

class DD : public Usable { };

DD dd;  // error: DD::DD() cannot access
        // Usable_lock::Usable_lock(): private  member
```

Could anybody explain me this code?

**EDIT**: Also another question i have is what is a virtual derivation and when is it needed?

Comment: Notice that this class does not do what it says on the tin - it does not prevent derivation. If it did, one would get an error message at the point the class is actually derived.

Comment: This is article about virtual inheritance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance. Why virtual inheritance is used here? To prevent multiple inheritance problems, when Usable class is derived from some other class, except Usable_lock.

Comment: Try editing to use this link instead: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation

"It relies on the fact that the most derived class in a hierarchy must construct a virtual base." Class DD is doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a property of `virtual` derivation.

The idea of `virtual` derivation is to solve the "Dreaded Diamond Pattern":

```
struct Base {};

struct D1: Base {};
struct D2: Base {};

struct TopDiamond: D1, D2 {};
```

The problem here is that `TopDiamond` has 2 instance of `Base` here.

To solve this problem, very peculiar "MultiInheritance", C++ uses the `virtual` keyword and what is thus called "virtual inheritance".

If we change the way `D1` and `D2` are defined such that:

```
struct D1: virtual Base {};
struct D2: virtual Base {};
```

Then there will only be one instance of `Base` within `TopDiamond`: the job of actually instantiating it is left to the top-constructor (here `TopDiamond`).

Thus, the little trick you have shown is simply explained here:

- because `Usable` derives virtually from `Usable_lock`, it's up to its derived class to instantiate the `Usable_lock` part of the object
- because `Usable_lock` constructor is `private`, only itself and `Usable` (friend) can access the constructor

It's clever, I had never thought of that. I wonder what the cost of `virtual` inheritance is here (extra memory / speed overhead) ?

Comment: Yup, this sums it up quite nicely. I'd spend a little less time on explaining what virtual inheritance is generally good for, but then I was to lazy to write an answer myself. `:)` +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

class `Usable_lock`'s Constructor is declared under Private 
So it is not accessible Outside

```
Usable_lock class
```

when you make object of

```
 DD dd;
```

It will call constructor of `Usable` and `Usable_Lock` both (because `DD` derived from `Usable` and `Usable` Derived from `Usable_lock`)

and thus it can't access Usable_Lock's Constructor.. and it will give you error

Comment: However `class Usable` is a friend and so should be able to access it. `DD` should not be accessing `Usable_lock`, it's `Usable` s job (?).

Comment: @Pasi: `Usable_lock` is a `virtual` base, so derived classes need to be able to access one of its constructors. Unfortunately, mihirpmehta's answer fails to mention that.

Comment: @sbi yes very true... i failed to mention that... ;(

Answer (score 1):

There are two points here:

1) Why Usable instance can be created, though it involves private Usable_lock constructor? Because Usable is friend of Usable_lock.

2) Why Usable-derived instance cannot be created? Because it involves private Usable_lock constructor.

Comment: Hint - it's about `virtual` derivation.